# How to use same windows partition over different analytical function in optimal way?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a question on the below code. I am using the same windows partition and running different functions such as max, min and row_number on it. Does Spark perform the windows partitioning every time I refer in `withColumn` or does it performs windows partitioning optimally one time as it encounters multiple functions on the same windows partition?

```
val windows = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("date").desc)

dataframe.withColumn("max", max(col("column1")).over(windows))
         .withColumn("min", min(col("column2")).over(windows))
         .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(windows))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark will do all aggregations over the same window at the same time.

We can confirm that by checking *physical plan* prepared by *catalyst*. *Catalyst* is an optimization engine, which optimizes all operations performed on the dataset. You can view *physical plan* by calling `explain(true)` on dataset:

```
val df = List(("1", "2019-01-01", "100", "66"), ("2", "2019-01-02", "555", "444"))
           .toDF("id", "date", "column1", "column2")

val windows = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("date").desc)

dataframe.withColumn("max", max(col("column1")).over(windows))
     .withColumn("min", min(col("column2")).over(windows))
     .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(windows))
     .explain(true)
```

In my case plan  looks like:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Window [max(column1#26) windowspecdefinition(id#24, date#25 DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS max#503, min(column2#27) windowspecdefinition(id#24, date#25 DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS min#510, row_number() windowspecdefinition(id#24, date#25 DESC NULLS LAST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS row_number#518], [id#24], [date#25 DESC NULLS LAST]
+- *(1) Sort [id#24 ASC NULLS FIRST, date#25 DESC NULLS LAST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#24, 200)
      +- LocalTableScan [id#24, date#25, column1#26, column2#27]
```

So as you can see Spark will do the following steps:

- sort whole dataset
- partition dataset over id
- go through all rows in dataset (scan) to perform aggregations